# LongListSelector with items of variable height & content

Tags: windows-phone-8, itemtemplate, longlistselector

I've used and am familiar with LongListSelector having a specific item template for all the items listed.

Now I try to implement a more complex LongListSelector where the items added will not be of fixed height/specific content. Could be a couple of textblocks and images in one case and 2 times the same elements in another (it's a set of elements that appears 1,2 or 3 times per item).

Note: I use ObservableCollection which I connect with the LongListSelector.

```
ObservableCollection<RouteInformation> Routes = new ObservableCollection<RouteInformation>();

        public RoutePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RoutesLongListSelector.ItemsSource = Routes;
        }
```

and I populate the list by pulling data from a database and in the end adding them with

```
Routes.Add(new RouteInformation(..., ...));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the criteria for the layout? How do you know which template you need for which item? There is a thing called data template selector.

Comment: The layout of each item is determined by the values I get from the pulled data. Could be 3-lines layout, maybe 5 or 7. The type model I use (RouteInformation) is the same for all the cases.

Comment: There *has* to be a place where you decide how many lines you need, where is that? If you cannot answer that, how can anyone else?

Comment: When the user navigates to a specific page, the constructor calls a function which returns the data I need to decide the number of lines. So, I should define 3 data templates in xaml and finally add the corresponding items in my ObservableCollection?

Comment: Will all items on *one* page have the same layout? Or will there be a mixed combination of layouts?

Comment: Yeah, all items of a page will be of the same layout. So, one Route would be of 5-line items while another (we're talking about the same page re-populated) would be of 3-line ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define multiple item templates in the page's resources:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate3Line">...
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<LongListSelector x:Name="lls">
```

and in the code behind depending on your condition, select custom data template:

```
 if (...)
    lls.ItemTemplate = Resources["ItemTemplate3Line"] as DataTemplate;
```